# Append compiler flags when running make

Tags: c++, makefile, compilation, gnu-make, compiler-flags

I would like to append flags to the compiler flags when running `make`, without altering the Makefile in anyway, e.g.

```
make CXX_FLAGS+='-DDEBUG'
```

The above treats "+=" as "=", so it's not the correct symbol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to modify the variable as `override` in your Makefile once. And then you can do what you want to do.

Here's the example,

Makefile:

```
override CFLAGS+=-g                                                                                    

app: main.c
  gcc $(CFLAGS) -o app main.c
```

Run the make:

```
$ make
gcc -g -o app main.c
```

Append the '-Wall' to $CFLAGS from the command:

```
$ make CFLAGS=-Wall
gcc -Wall -g -o app main.c
```

Work fine here. And here's [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Override-Directive) you can reference.

Comment: Or use `override CFLAGS := -g $(CFLAGS)` if the order is important.

Comment: Nit pick question: Let's say I have a definition SKIP_FEATURE.  If this is defined, I don't want to compile the source file feature.cpp and/or not link feature.o.  How would I accomplish this?